# Why am I having an issue with some SSL certificates in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate

Trying to access `duckduckgo.com` and `reddit.com` from FireFox 69 results in the following error.

Google Chrome does not have this issue and reports that the certificate is valid. This just started happening today.

I am running Fedora 30.

[image: screenshot of error message]

I can't access `quora.com` either.

---

**Update:**

I did a `pkill firefox` and after restoring my session, everything appears to be fixed. That was very strange.

Comment: Did you read the message? It says that the error may be caused by locally installed software that intercepts your connection, such as a virus scanner. Do you have such software installed?

Comment: No. I'm running Linux.

Comment: Are you on a corporate/school/etc. network?

Comment: I'm on my home network.

Comment: Do you have any add-ons installed in Firefox that could be interfering?

Comment: Just Adblock Plus and NoSquint Plus.

Comment: That's really strange. This error indicates something is intercepting your HTTPS connection (on your computer or in your network). It's unlikely to be fixed by a restart... maybe you connected differently the second time? Anyway, I added an answer with more details.

Comment: I'm having the same problem from time to time. Restarting fixes everything. I created a bug report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1766895

Comment: Bug-report update: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1752303

Comment: Thanks for asking the question, Zhro, and thanks for posting that link, Gerald. I have been getting this error message intermittently for the past few weeks in Firefox on Arch Linux, even though there should not be any software MITMing me. I was a little concerned that there might be a real problem, even though it goes away after restarting Firefox, but I wasn't able to find any explanation until I came across your comment.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

This means that Firefox cannot ensure the connection to this site is properly secured, **and that the same problem has occured with other sites, too**.

### Details

The actual, technical error that Firefox detected is indicated by the error code at the end, namely:

```
MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_MITM_DETECTED
```

This means that Firefox believes some third party is intercepting your HTTPS connection to the website you are trying to load.

Actually, there are two different error codes that can be shown in that situation: `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`, and `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_MITM_DETECTED`. Both mean that the HTTPS certificate which Firefox received when accessing the site is signed by a certificate authority Firefox does not trust.

`MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_MITM_DETECTED` is a newer variant of `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` (introduced in Firefox 61, see [Bug 1450967](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1450967) - though the error page came later). This error is shown if Firefox runs into the same unknown certificate authority on multiple different sites, which indicates that the problem is not with the remote site, but with your computer or connection. See e.g. [the community discussion "MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_MITM_DETECTED"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/forums/contributors/713076) for details.

And for anyone *really* curious, the check for this problem in Firefox's source code is in [security/certverifier/CertVerifier.cpp](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/0b797e7d2e175006d174e814a0e4a07362188ed9/security/certverifier/CertVerifier.cpp#L896).

### How to solve

Ideally, you would disable whatever software is intercepting your connection - since that can generally undermine the security provided by HTTPS.

However, if you do not want to (or cannot) do this, you can import the CA used by the intercepting software into Firefox to make it trust the CA. Alternatively, and specifically on Windows or MacOS, if other browsers do not show an error when loading the site, it is possible that the CA's certificate was installed into the certificate store provided by the operating system. Most other browsers, such as Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, use this store by default, while Firefox has its own certificate store. To make Firefox use the certificate store provided by the operating system, [set the internal preference 
`security.enterprise_roots.enabled`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox).